# geopandas : Obtain min , max lat and long for all geometries

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I am reading a shapefile of a county and need to extract the min and max coordinates across all geometries. It seems like this is possible with each individual geometries in the shapefile with `shapely` but not across all geometries in shapefile.

```
sf_shp = os.getcwd() + '/data/map/San_Mateo/SAN_MATEO_COUNTY_STREETS.shp'
sfgeodata = gpd.read_file(sf_shp)

sfgeodata.total_bounds <-- for bounding box.
```

Is there a property or a function to obtain this info in geopandas or any other packages?

Answer (score 2):

[`total_bounds`](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.total_bounds.html) returns a tuple containing `minx`, `miny`, `maxx`, `maxy` values for the bounds of the series as a whole.

[`bounds`](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.bounds.html) returns a DataFrame with columns `minx`, `miny`, `maxx`, `maxy` values containing the bounds for each geometry.

*Viz.*——

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import box
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.bounds
world.total_bounds

# bounds for individual geometries
poly_geom = world.bounds
b = poly_geom.apply(lambda row: box(row.minx, row.miny, row.maxx, row.maxy), axis=1)
boxes = gpd.GeoDataFrame(poly_geom, geometry=b)

# visualize
ax = world.plot()
boxes.boundary.plot(color='r', ax=ax)
plt.show()

# total bounds for all geometries
world_box = gpd.GeoSeries(box(*world.total_bounds))

# visualize
ax = world.plot()
world_box.boundary.plot(color='r', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

`bounds`:

[image]

`total_bounds`:

[image]